# Continuation (call/cc) in Scheme

Tags: scheme, continuations, callcc

I need to understand Continuations in Scheme for my upcoming exams and I have no idea about continuations at all. Can anyone please suggest me sources of how to go about learning continuations?

Regards,

darkie

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612761/what-is-call-cc

Comment: @Dave: The thread seems to be talking about other programming languages not of my interest. Additionally, the information provided by Alex below is better from a beginner's perspective. Please let me know if any such links exist for beginners

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find this [short draft tutorial](http://phillipwright.info/drafts/continuations.htm) a useful starting point.  Once you grasp those very basics, a more extensive, Scheme-specific coverage is [here](http://community.schemewiki.org/?call-with-current-continuation); for a broader purview, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) can be of some help (and has a few good links at the end).

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have a query from the link 'short draft tutorial'. The example has (+ 2 (call/cc (lambda (k) (set! handle k) 2))). Why do we have the rightmost 2 here? Is it because we need to associate the handle with continuation initially or is there some other reason to it?

Comment: @darkie15, the rightmost `2` is the value the `call/cc` returns, making the expression result `4` (since that's `(+ 2 2)`!-); as a _side effect_, the `lambda` sets name `handle` to the continuation, so the short tutorial shows how to then treat `handle` like a function which performs `(+ 2 whatever)` on its argument `whatever`.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [this short article](http://home.vmathew.in/writings/yaaec-yet-another-attempt-to-explain-continuations) to make myself more acquainted with continuations. You may find it useful. I have also collected some links there.

Comment: this domain is unavailable