# How does this Scheme list iterator use call-with-current-continuation?

Tags: iterator, scheme, continuations

I'm trying to read this code:

```
(define list-iter
  (lambda (a-list)
    (define iter
      (lambda ()
        (call-with-current-continuation control-state)))
    (define control-state
      (lambda (return)
        (for-each
          (lambda (element)
            (set! return (call-with-current-continuation
                           (lambda (resume-here)
                             (set! control-state resume-here)
                             (return element)))))
          a-list)
        (return 'list-ended)))
    iter))
```

Can anyone explain how `call-with-current-continuation` works in this example?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of probably a zillion other "what is call/cc" questions on SO. The most canonical and apparently-helpful one I could find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612761/what-is-call-cc.

Comment: I figured this specific example, using a `yield`-like pattern, was useful enough to stand on its own. Maybe it should be retitled, though.

Answer (score 3):

The essence of `call-with-concurrent-continuation`, or `call/cc` for short, is the ability to grab checkpoints, or continuations, during the execution of a program. Then, you can go back to those checkpoints by applying them like functions.

Here's a simple example where the continuation isn't used:

```
> (call/cc (lambda (k) (+ 2 3)))
5
```

If you don't use the continuation, it's hard to tell the difference. Here's a few where we actually use it:

```
> (call/cc (lambda (k) (+ 2 (k 3))))
3
> (+ 4 (call/cc (lambda (k) (+ 2 3))))
9
> (+ 4 (call/cc (lambda (k) (+ 2 (k 3)))))
7
```

When the continuation is invoked, control flow jumps back to where the continuation was grabbed by `call/cc`. Think of the `call/cc` expression as a hole that gets filled by whatever gets passed to `k`.

`list-iter` is a substantially more complex use of `call/cc`, and might be a difficult place to begin using it. First, here's an example usage:

```
> (define i (list-iter '(a b c)))
> (i)
a
> (i)
b
> (i)
c
> (i)
list-ended
> (i)
list-ended
```

Here's a sketch of what's happening:

1. `list-iter` returns a procedure of no arguments `i`.
2. When `i` is invoked, we grab a continuation immediately and pass it to `control-state`. When that continuation, bound to `return`, is invoked, we'll immediately return to whoever invoked `i`.
3. For each element in the list, we grab a new continuation and overwrite the definition of `control-state` with that new continuation, meaning that we'll resume from there the next time step 2 comes along.
4. After setting up `control-state` for the next time through, we pass the current element of the list back to the `return` continuation, yielding an element of the list.
5. When `i` is invoked again, repeat from step 2 until the `for-each` has done its work for the whole list.
6. Invoke the `return` continuation with `'list-ended`. Since `control-state` isn't updated, it will keep returning `'list-ended` every time `i` is invoked.

As I said, this is a fairly complex use of `call/cc`, but I hope this is enough to get through this example. For a gentler introduction to continuations, I'd recommend picking up [The Seasoned Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/026256100X).

Answer (score 0):

Basically it takes a function `f` as its parameter, and applies `f` to the current context/state of the program.

From wikipedia:
`(define (f return)`
 `(return 2)`
 `3)`

`(display (f (lambda (x) x))) ; displays 3`

`(display (call-with-current-continuation f)) ; displays 2`

So basically when f is called without current-continuation (cc), the function is applied to 2, and then returns 3.  When using current-continuation, the parameter is applied to 2, which forces the program to jump to the point where the current-continuation was called, and thus returns 2.  It can be used to generate returns, or to suspend execution flow.

If you know C, think about it like this: in C, you can take a pointer to a function.  You also have a return mechanism.  Suppose the return took a parameter of the same type the function takes.  Suppose you could take its address and store that address in a variable or pass it as a parameter, and allow functions to return for you.  It can be used to mimic throw/catch, or as a mechanism for coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially:

```
(define (consume)
  (write (call/cc control)))

(define (control ret)
   (set! ret (call/cc (lambda (resume)
                        (set! control resume)
                        (ret 1))))
   (set! ret (call/cc (lambda (resume)
                        (set! control resume)
                        (ret 2))))
   (set! ret (call/cc (lambda (resume)
                        (set! control resume)
                        (ret 3)))))

(consume)
(consume)
(consume)
```

Hope it is easier to understand.