# Which simplest evaluation model explains call/cc?

Tags: scheme, semantics, evaluation, interpretation, callcc

TL;DR: What does call/cc do, (semi-)formally speaking?

The long version: I'm vaguely familiar with continuations and call/cc, but I don't have a strong formal understanding. I would like one.

In the [SICP video lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE18841CABEA24090) we are presented with the substitution model and a metacircular interpreter. In Shriram Krishnamurti's [programming language course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbjZkI1beTSM2AlyXH3KudhmNs9Xn3Z1b) we are shown an environment-and-store-passing style. In the compiler course I took in uni I evaluated Java expressions by manipulating a stack.

What's the simplest evaluation model in which call/cc can be expressed, and how do you express call/cc in it?

Comment: [cs.se] would be a better place for a theoretical question like this. [so] is for questions about actual code.

Comment: How do I migrate my question? Copy-paste?

Comment: I've written a lot of answers to how `call/cc` [relates to code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55788192/1565698) and after representing the code in CPS you can do substitution model as long as you don't mutate with `set` and friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this excellent presentation (in German), which answered my question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuaM9-PX1ls

To evaluate the lambda calculus with call/CC, you pass around an *evaluation context* consisting of an environment (as usual) *and a call stack*. A call to `call/cc` creates a special function-like continuation object which stores the evaluation context. The result of applying the special object to an expression `expr` is the result of interpreting `expr` in the evaluation context captured in the continuation object.

TL;DR: you can implement `call/cc` with an environment-and-call-stack-passing interpreter.

If you want to also thread around a mutable store the continuation objects should not capture it. Rather, when invoking a continuation you pass the store as an argument to the interpretation in the restored evaluation context. (The store can be of a linear type.)

Here is one such implementation in Haskell.  Here's a sample expression you may want to evaluate: `interpret 0 (Application (Lambda (1, (CallCC (Lambda (2, (Application (Variable 2) (Lambda (3, (Variable 4))))))))) (Lambda (4, (Variable 5))))`.

(The numbers are just plain old names, not (e.g.) De Bruijn indices.  If you wish to use characters or strings, change `type Name = Integer` to `type Name = Char`.)

Note especially `interp` applied to `CallCC` and `InvokeContinuation` as well as `continue` applied to `ContinuationArgument`.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type Name = Integer
type NameAndBody = (Name, LambdaCallCC)
data LambdaCallCC
  = Lambda NameAndBody
  | Variable Name
  | InvokeContinuation EvaluationContext LambdaCallCC
  | CallCC LambdaCallCC
  | Application LambdaCallCC LambdaCallCC
  deriving Show

type Environment = Map.Map Name NameAndBody

type EvaluationContext = (CallStack, Environment)
type CallStack = [Frame]

data Frame
  = FunctionPosition LambdaCallCC
  | ArgumentPosition NameAndBody
  | ContinuationArgument EvaluationContext
  deriving Show

type Fail = (Name, EvaluationContext)
interpret :: Name -> LambdaCallCC -> Either Fail NameAndBody
interpret thunkVarName expression = interp [] Map.empty expression
  where interp stk env (Lambda nameAndBody)
          = continue stk env nameAndBody
        interp stk env (Variable name)
          = case Map.lookup name env of
              Nothing -> Left (name, (stk, env))
              Just e -> continue stk env e
        interp stk env (Application e1 e2)
          = interp (FunctionPosition e2 : stk) env e1
        interp stk env (CallCC expr)
          = interp stk env (Application expr
                              (Lambda (thunkVarName,
                                        (InvokeContinuation
                                          (stk, env)
                                          (Variable thunkVarName)))))
        interp stk env (InvokeContinuation capturedContext expr)
          = interp [ContinuationArgument capturedContext] env expr

        continue [] env value
          = Right value
        continue ((FunctionPosition expr) : frames) env value
          = interp ((ArgumentPosition value) : frames) env expr
        continue ((ArgumentPosition (name, body)) : frames) env value
          = interp frames (Map.insert name value env) body
        continue ((ContinuationArgument (stk, env)) : nil) _ value
          = interp stk env (Lambda value)
```

Comment: Per Jonas "To evaluate the lambda calculus with call/CC, you pass around an evaluation context consisting of an environment (as usual) and a call stack" The call stack is the secret sauce.

Answer (score 2):

*TL;DR `call/cc` lets you tap into Schemes internal code so that you can use continuations without writing your code in continuation passing style. The best evaluation model is the substitution model given that you don't use `set` and view it from CPS code*

Imagine this little program.

```
(define (sum-list lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((number? (car lst)) (+ (car lst) (sum-list (cdr lsr))))
        (else (sum-list (cdr lsr)))))

(display (sum-list '(1 2 3 4))) ; displays 10
```

Imagine you want the result to be `1337` if you hit the `else` term. How would you go about that without rewriting the whole thing? You can't. However most Scheme implementation does CPS conversion to your code where changing it is trivial:

```
(define (sum-list& lst k)
  (null?& lst
          (lambda (nlst?)
            (if& nlst?
                 (lambda ()
                   (k 0))
                 (lambda ()
                   (car& lst
                         (lambda (car-lst)
                           (number?& car-lst
                                     (lambda (ncl?)
                                       (if& ncl?
                                            (lambda ()
                                              (cdr& lst
                                                    (lambda (clst)
                                                      (sum-list& clst
                                                                 (lambda (sclst)
                                                                   (+& car-lst sclst k))))))
                                            (lambda ()
                                              (cdr& lst
                                                    (lambda (clst)
                                                      (sum-list& clst k))))))))))))))
(sum-list& '(1 2 3 4)
           (lambda (sum)
             (display& sum halt)))
```

`cond` is a macro so it is the `if&` calls you see. I know what you're thinking. Why not tell the programmers to do it like this in the first place? Just kidding!

If you change the second continuation in the second `if&` to `(lambda () (k 1337))` you're done. As beautiful as CPS is it is horrible to read and write, but since the compiler does this anyway couldn't there be a way to be able to write your code in the first way and still get to code control flow? The best of two worlds is enabled with `call/cc`. `call/cc` is this in CPS:

```
(define (call/cc& f& continuation)
  (define (exit& value actual-continuation)
    (continuation value))
  (f& exit& continuation))
```

It doesn't do much at all. It passes `exit&` which ignores the real continuation of the program when called and calls the value with the original continuation of the `call/cc&` call. With the list `'(1 2 3 #f)` you'd have 3 nested continuations waiting to add with the result but all of that needs to be cancelled. If you get to choose the value of the continuation before that calculation it automatically is cancelled. 
And that is it. When you write your code with it you don't need to do full CPS, only the continuation you want thought `call/cc` like this:

```
(define (sum-list lst)
  (call/cc
   (lambda (k)
     (define (helper lst)
       (cond ((null? lst) 0)
             ((number? (car lst))
              (+ (car lst) (helper (cdr lst))))
             (else (k 1337))))
     (helper lst))))
```

This gets transformed to this in CPS:

```
(define (sum-list& lst k)
  (call/cc&
   (lambda (k& real-k)
     (define (helper& lst k)
       (null?& lst
               (lambda (nlst?)
                 (if& nlst?
                      (lambda ()
                        (k 0))
                      (lambda ()
                        (car& lst
                              (lambda (car-lst)
                                (number?& car-lst
                                          (lambda (ncl?)
                                            (if& ncl?
                                                 (lambda ()
                                                   (cdr& lst
                                                         (lambda (clst)
                                                           (helper& clst
                                                                    (lambda (sclst)
                                                                      (+& car-lst sclst k))))))
                                                 (lambda ()
                                                   (k& 1337 real-k))))))))))))
     (helper& lst real-k))
     k))


(sum-list& '(1 2 3 4)
           (lambda (sum)
             (display& sum halt)))
```

`call/cc` can always be avoided. Our example could have been rewritten to return 1337 like this:

```
(define (sum-list lst)
  (define (helper lst sum)
    (cond ((null? lst) sum)
          ((number? (car lst)) (helper (cdr lst) (+ sum (car lst))))
          (else 1337)))
  (helper lst 0))
```

This is tail recursive and instead of creating continuations it accumulates. For completeness here is the CPS version of it:

```
(define (helper& lst sum k)
  (null?& lst
          (lambda (nlst)
            (if& nlst
                 (lambda () (k sum))
                 (lambda ()
                   (car& lst
                       (lambda (cl)
                         (number?& cl
                                 (lambda (ncl?)
                                   (if& ncl?
                                        (lambda ()
                                          (cdr& lst
                                                (lambda (cdrl)
                                                  (+& sum
                                                      cl
                                                      (lambda (scl)
                                                        (helper& cdrl
                                                                 scl
                                                                 k))))))
                                        (lambda () (k 1337))))))))))))


(define (sum-list& lst k)
  (helper& lst 0 k))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here's my summary: let `prog` be a syntax tree and `f` be a program transformation (CPS). To evaluate `prog`, evaluate `(f prog)` in some appropriate model. Is that right? If so, is there some local evaluation of `prog` rather than `(f prog)` that can be done in an X-passing style, where X is e.g. a triple of `(environment, store, ???)` with `???` being e.g. a spaghetti stack? Is there a something-passing evaluation model which doesn't rewrite the program?

Comment: @JonasKölker No. Even Scheme implementation that doesn't do CPS pass by default does it when they detect `call/cc` being used. eg. Ikarus does it like this. How can you otherwise return a procedure that represents the rest of the program? You haven't told us what language you're trying to implement your Scheme in, but while it might be a way to get the same result without CPS it would be harder than CPS. Matt Might has some [excellent papers](http://matt.might.net/articles/) on programming language design and a lot focusing on Scheme and CPS

Comment: Often you find someone has implemented Scheme without tail calls and `call/cc`. That means they use normal stack with no TCO and they don't have CPS. A usable language, but hardly Scheme.