# call cc example racket

Tags: scheme, racket, continuations, callcc

I'm analyzing this code regarding the use of `call/cc`. This function is kind of mystical, and it's quite complicated to fully understand.

I really cannot understand how this code is working. Below is my interpretation.

```
(define (print+sub x y)
  (display x)
  (display " ")
  (display y)
  (display " -> ")
  (- x y))

(define (puzzle)
  (call/cc (lambda (exit)
             (define (local e)
               (call/cc
                (lambda (local-exit)
                  (exit (print+sub e
                           (call/cc
                            (lambda (new-exit)
                              (set! exit new-exit)
                              (local-exit #f))))))))
             (local 6)
             (exit 2))))

(define x (puzzle))
```

`call/cc` is called through

```
    call/cc (lambda(exit))
```

and then again through

```
              (call/cc
                (lambda (local-exit)
```

The function `local` is called with parameter `6` which is passed to `print+sub` as `x`. But how does the value `2` arrives to `print+sub` as `y`?

And the most important part, what is the order in which all these instructions are performed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is call/cc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612761/what-is-call-cc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `(puzzle)` sets up a continuation `exit` such that calling `(exit val)` is the same as if *that call* `(puzzle)` had just returned that `val` value.

Then the call `(local 6)` is made. It sets up a continuation `local-exit` such that calling `(local-exit val2)` is the same as if *that call* `(local 6)` had just returned that `val2` value. Of course that return value is ignored, and the next call, `(exit 2)` would be made next.

Now, after setting up `local-exit`, the call `(exit (print+sub e ...))` is made. It needs to find out the value `val3` of `(print+sub e ...)` first, so it could pass it to the call `(exit val3)`.

`print+sub` expects two parameters. The call has two expressions which must be evaluated, so the values found, if any, will be passed as `x` and `y` to `print+sub`.

Evaluating `e` is simple. It is `6`.

Evaluating the second expression, `(call/cc (lambda (new-exit) ...))`, sets up yet another continuation, `new-exit`, such that calling `(new-exit y)` is equivalent to returning that `y` into that slot `{y}` awaiting it in the call `(print+sub 6 {y})`.

Then the body of

```
      (lambda (new-exit)
          (set! exit new-exit)
          (local-exit #f))
```

is entered. `(set! exit new-exit)` changes the meaning of any call `(exit val)` to be from now on the same as if `(new-exit val)` was called instead.

Now, finally, `(local-exit #f)` is called. It jumps out of the `(local 6)` call,  *immediately* returning that `#f`, which is then ignored. The call `(exit 2)` is made. It is the same as if the call `(new-exit 2)` was made. That means returning `2` into that `{y}` slot, so the call `(print+sub e 2)` ***inside `(exit (print+sub e 2))`*** is now performed.

`print+sub` prints what it prints and returns `4`, so that `(exit 4)` is now called.

Now the crucial tidbit is, what is the value of `exit` used here? Is it the original `exit` continuation, or the changed one, `new-exit`?

Suppose the Scheme standard says that in any function application *`(foo a1 a2 ... an)`* `foo` is evaluated first, *then* `ai`s are evaluated in an unspecified order, *then* the functional value is applied to the `n` argument values just found. This would mean that this `exit` to be called is the original `exit` continuation, and so the value `4` is returned as the final value of the original call `(puzzle)` (this is what really happens in DrRacket).

Suppose the Scheme standard doesn't say this. Then `exit` could actually be `new-exit` now. Calling it would thus lead to an infinite loop. This is *not* what happens in DrRacket.

Indeed if we replace `exit` with `(lambda (v) (exit v))`,

```
           ((lambda (v) (exit v))
                (print+sub e
                           (call/cc
                            (lambda (new-exit)
                              (set! exit new-exit)
                              (local-exit #f))))))))
```

the code does go into the infinite loop.

---

Continuations are like jump (a `GOTO`) with a value. When we have some code like `...... (foo) .....` with a normal function `foo`, when the evaluation of `foo` ends, the returned value is used further in that code, according to what's written there.

With `puzzle` used as `foo`, the evaluation proceeds the same. Scheme attempts to find out the return value of `puzzle` to use it further in the surrounding code.

But `puzzle` calls `call/cc` immediately, so it creates this marker, a `GOTO` label to go to, so that when / if / deep inside `puzzle` a call is made to `(exit 42)`, the control jumps to - *goes to* - that marker, that label, and  `42` is used as the return value.

So when deep inside `(puzzle)` a call `(exit 42)` is made, it has the same effect as if that call to `(puzzle)` has just returned with the `42` as the return value into its surrounding code, without going through all the remaining code inside `puzzle`.

That's how continuations work. A continuation is a marker to jump to, with a value, to be used in the subsequent code as if returned normally by the preceding piece of code.

---

The code can be a bit easier to read with Racket's [`let/cc`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._let%2Fcc%29%29), or an equivalent macro:

```
(define-syntax with-current-continuation    ; let/cc
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ c a b ...)
     (call/cc (lambda (c) a b ...)))))

(define (puzzle2)
  (let/cc exit  ; --->>--------------->>------------>>-------------.
    (define (local e)                                            ; |
      (let/cc local-exit  ; --->>----------------------------.     |
        (exit (print+sub e                                 ; |     |
                         (let/cc new-exit  ;  -->>----.      |     |
                           (set! exit new-exit)    ;  |      |     |
                           (local-exit #f))        ;  |      |     |
                                          ;; --<<-----*      |     |
                         )))                               ; |     |
                           ;; --<<-----------------<<--------*     |
      )                                                          ; |
    (local 6)                                                    ; |
    (exit 2))                                                    ; |
            ;; --<<---------------<<------------------<<-----------*
  )
```

Imagine you're in a debugger and you've placed a breakpoint on the *closing bracket* of each `let/cc` form. Each continuation, if invoked, jumps directly to its defining `let/cc`'s closing paren, so that the passed value is used as that expression's return value in the subsequent calculations.  That's basically it.

The mind-bending part though is that in Scheme, you can jump to the closing paren from *outside* that form, thus re-entering old control context.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! May I ask you if you can explain more what do you mean with "Calling (puzzle) sets up a continuation exit such that calling (exit val) is the same as if that call (puzzle) had just returned that val value."?