# What information does this statement reveal about the function f in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

```
(*function f's definition*)
fun f l j y  = l j y
val f = fn : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c
```

What does the below line say about the function f ?

```
val f = fn : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question it helps to rename your identifiers:

```
fun apply g x y = g x y;
val apply = fn : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c
```

`apply` is equivalent to what you are calling `f`. What apply does, informally, is take a function, `g`, of two variables (in [curried form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)) and two arguments `x,y` and actually applies g to those arguments.

As an example `g`, define:

```
fun sum x y = x + y;
val sum = fn : int -> int -> int
```

Then, for example:

```
apply sum 5 7;
val it = 12 : int
```

In the type signature of `apply` the part

```
('a -> 'b -> 'c)
```

is the type of `g`. It is polymorphic. You can apply any function to arguments of an appropriate type. When you actually use `apply` (as I did above with `sum`) then the SML compiler will have enough information to figure out what concrete types correspond to the type variables `'a, 'b, 'c`. the overall type of apply is

```
('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c
```

which says that `apply` is a function which, when fed a function of type `('a -> 'b -> 'c)` and arguments of type `'a` and `'b`, produces a result of type `'c`. I'm not sure of any immediate use of `apply`, though it does serve to emphasize the perspective that functional application is itself a higher-order function.

Comment: John coleman. Thank you. I am learning SML and I am having hard time understand continuation. Can you tell me any tutorial or any other way from where I can learn more about continuation.

Comment: Unlike some functional languages such as Scheme, continuations are not part of SML -- though various implementations of SML such as SML/NJ provide their own implementations (e.g. SMLofNJ.Cont.callcc). I haven't tried any of them. You could perhaps post another question and someone with experience with them could answer. Before you post another question, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956717/what-do-continuations-mean-in-functional-programmingspecfically-sml?rq=1